# excel move across a row with reference moving down a column using OFFSET

Tags: excel, excel-formula, offset

I want the following:

```
c31='Monthly Summary'!d5
d31='Monthly Summary'!d6
f31='Monthly Summary'!d7
g31='Monthly Summary'!d8
```

I know you can do this with offset but im not that great at it.

Here's my failed attempt:

```
=OFFSET('Monthly Summary'!$D$3,1,ROW()-31)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
c31='Monthly Summary'!d5  =OFFSET('Monthly Summary'!$D$3,2,0)
d31='Monthly Summary'!d6  =OFFSET('Monthly Summary'!$D$3,3,0)
f31='Monthly Summary'!d7  =OFFSET('Monthly Summary'!$D$3,4,0)
g31='Monthly Summary'!d8  =OFFSET('Monthly Summary'!$D$3,5,0)
```

If you'll see, `'Monthly Summary'!$D$3`is reference cell in `OFFSET` formula, so if you want to get value of `'Monthly Summary'!$D$5` you have to move two rows down in the same column. Hence, for `Cell C31` row parameter is 2 and column parameter is 0. Same applies for other cells.

**OR**

In `Cell C31` enter the following formula

```
=OFFSET('Monthly Summary'!$D$3,COLUMN()-1,ROW()-31)
```

then drag/copy above formula across. This should work for you.

Feel free to ask if anything is not clear.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the 2nd formula is exactly what i wanted!